# generate a date sequence of last day of month in R

Tags: r, date, sequence

If I give a start date and end date, and a frequency I should be able to generate a sequence of dates from start to end such that

1) **the dates are the last day of the month**.
2) I can set the frequency of sequence to any factor of 12 (wrt 12 months). Say if the frequency is 3, it means there is an interval or gap of 4 months.

For (1) the following function gives me an output with an interval of 3 months (ie quarterly)but it doesn't give the dates with last day of the month.

```
    DateSeq<-function(st,en, freq){
    seq(st, en, by = paste(as.character(12/freq), "months"))
    }
    DateSeq(as.Date("2015-01-01"),as.Date("2018-03-03"),4)
```

how to convert this to a sequence that gives me last day.? Give me a simple code.

Comment: Perhaps `DateSeq(as.Date("2015-02-01"),as.Date("2018-04-03"),4)-1`

Comment: @akrun thats not an elegent solution.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how u define elegant.  It is just subtracting 1 from the function.

Comment: This does not work.                                                                                         
      DateSeq(as.Date("2016-01-31"),as.Date("2018-03-03"),4)-1                   
 I should be able to do this for any startdate or end.

Comment: Okay, then u should mention it in the post.  I thought ur dates will be the first of month

Comment: You just subtracted 1 day from the sequence. If I put start date as Jan 31, the result shows start date as Jan 30. Regardless of whatever start date, I should get each value in the sequence as last day of the month

Comment: I got it.  It was based on your example

Comment: @akrun , there is a function in chron called seq.date but I cannot set frequency like 6 months or 4 months.

Comment: here I can set frequency but its not giving me the last date

Comment: How about `lubridate::ceiling_date(DateSeq(as.Date("2015-01-10"),as.Date("2018-03-20"),4), 'month')-1`

Comment: ceiling_date(DateSeq(as.Date("2015-01-31"),as.Date("2015-04-30"),4), 'month')-1

Comment: What is the problem with that one

Comment: The problem is its not giving correct values for some values. Like 2nd value should be 2015-04-30 not 2015-05-31

Comment: Problem comes when start day is 30 or 31st of a month

Comment: If you look at your function it returns `DateSeq(as.Date("2015-01-31"),as.Date("2018-03-03"),4)
 #[1] "2015-01-31" "2015-05-01" "2015-07-31" "2015-10-31" "2016-01-31" "2016-05-01" "2016-07-31" "2016-10-31" "2017-01-31"
[10] "2017-05-01" "2017-07-31" "2017-10-31" "2018-01-31"` the 2nd value as May 1

Comment: Try this `library(zoo);DateSeq <- function(st, en, freq) {
  st <- as.Date(as.yearmon(st));  
  en <- as.Date(as.yearmon(en)); 
 as.Date(as.yearmon(seq(st, en, by = paste(as.character(12/freq), "months"))), frac = 1)
  
  }; DateSeq(as.Date("2015-01-31"),as.Date("2018-03-03"),4)`

Comment: But the difference between May01 and Jan31 is effectively 3 months.With yours , we got 4 month gap. we should get Apl 31 or 04-31. Any other way?

Comment: I find only 30 days in April. i.e. `DateSeq(as.Date("2015-01-31"),as.Date("2018-03-03"),4)#
 [1] "2015-01-31" "2015-04-30" "2015-07-31" "2015-10-31" "2016-01-31" "2016-04-30" "2016-07-31" "2016-10-31" "2017-01-31"
[10] "2017-04-30" "2017-07-31" "2017-10-31" "2018-01-31"`

Comment: That seems to be working I'll work and say if something is not right

Comment: @akrun write that as an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This gives a sequence of end-of-month dates from the year/month of `st` to the year/month of `en`.

```
library(zoo)
as.Date(seq(as.yearmon(st), as.yearmon(en), by = 1 / freq), frac = 1)
```

In the above `st` and `en` could be any class that converts to `yearmon` including `yearmon` itself, `Date`, character strings or numeric.  For example, `"2000-02-01"`, `"2000-02"`, `as.Date("2000-02-01")`, `2000+1/12`.

If `en` is a date and the end date of the sequence should be no later than `en` then replace `as.yearmon(en)` with the following which subtracts 1/12 if `en` is not at the end of the month.

```
as.yearmon(en) - (as.Date(en) < as.Date(as.yearmon(en), frac = 1)) / 12
```

Similarly if `st` is a date and the starting date of the sequence should be no later than `st` use the same idea to subtract 1/12 if `st` is not at the end of the month replacing `as.yearmon(st)` with

```
as.yearmon(st) - (as.Date(st) < as.Date(as.yearmon(st), frac = 1)) / 12
```

There is some question regarding whether we really need dates at all since they are always at the end of the month.  It seems that the point is to create a year/month sequence and the end-of-month dates are just a way to represent that. 
 A simpler way would be this `yearmon` sequence directly.

```
seq(as.yearmon(st), as.yearmon(en), by = 1 / freq)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can change the starting date and end date to the start of month before doing the `seq` using `as.yearmon` from `zoo` and later convert it to last day of month by the same conversion through `as.yearmon`

```
library(zoo)
DateSeq <- function(st, en, freq) {
  st <- as.Date(as.yearmon(st)) 
  en <- as.Date(as.yearmon(en)) 
  as.Date(as.yearmon(seq(st, en, by = paste(as.character(12/freq), "months"))), frac = 1)

 }
DateSeq(as.Date("2015-01-31"),as.Date("2018-03-03"),4)
#[1] "2015-01-31" "2015-04-30" "2015-07-31" "2015-10-31" "2016-01-31" "2016-04-30" "2016-07-31" "2016-10-31" "2017-01-31"
#[10] "2017-04-30" "2017-07-31" "2017-10-31" "2018-01-31"
```

Comment: @G.Grothendieck write that as an answer then. Seems to be a  more elegant code

Answer (score 1):

An approach using `time_seq()` from my package `timeplyr` that can handle monthly sequences.

```r
# remotes::install_github("NicChr/timeplyr")
library(timeplyr)

time_seq("2015-01-31", "2018-03-03", by = "3 months")
#>  [1] "2015-01-31" "2015-04-30" "2015-07-31" "2015-10-31" "2016-01-31"
#>  [6] "2016-04-30" "2016-07-31" "2016-10-31" "2017-01-31" "2017-04-30"
#> [11] "2017-07-31" "2017-10-31" "2018-01-31"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

It can handle zoo's yearmon class as well.

```r
library(lubridate)
time_range <- zoo::as.yearmon(ymd(c("2015-01-31", "2018-03-03")))

time_span(time_range, by = 3/12)
#>  [1] "Jan 2015" "Apr 2015" "Jul 2015" "Oct 2015" "Jan 2016" "Apr 2016"
#>  [7] "Jul 2016" "Oct 2016" "Jan 2017" "Apr 2017" "Jul 2017" "Oct 2017"
#> [13] "Jan 2018"
```