# Expand quarterly rows to multiple monthly rows

Tags: r, date, data.table, reshape, lubridate

I have a dataset with a column referring to date. The date is written in a quarterly manner (i.e. takes each 3 months as 1 unit).
One column indicates whether the date is in fact quarterly or monthly taken. I want only to deal with quarterly types.

I would like to expand each quarterly row to 3 monthly rows. Another column, called "gains" will be affected too and shall be divided by "3" (i.e. the number of months in a quarter).

Example:

```
example <- data.frame(quarterly_reports = as.Date(as.character(c(20200331,20200630, 20200930,20201231, 20210131)), "%Y%m%d"),
                      type = c("q","q","q","q","m"),
                      gains = c(18000, 30000, 45000, 60000, 10000))
```

This is how it looks like:

```
  quarterly_reports type gains
1        2020-03-31    q 18000
2        2020-06-30    q 30000
3        2020-09-30    q 45000
4        2020-12-31    q 60000
5        2021-01-31    m 10000
```

What I want is an output similar to this (and note how I divided the gains column by 3):

```
   quarterly_reports type gains
1         2020-01-31    m  6000
2         2020-02-28    m  6000
3         2020-03-31    m  6000
4         2020-04-30    m 10000
5         2020-05-31    m 10000
6         2020-06-30    m 10000
7         2020-07-31    m 15000
8         2020-08-31    m 15000
9         2020-09-30    m 15000
10        2020-10-31    m 20000
11        2020-11-30    m 20000
12        2020-12-31    m 20000
13        2021-01-31    m 10000
```

Note: I'm using `data.table`, and I'm trying to utilize `lubridate` in converting the dates from quarterly to monthly. I have about 3 millions of these rows, so I'm looking for something fast and dirty.

Any reply is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: based on @Henrik's suggestions, here is a much-more efficient alternative:

```r
library(lubdridate)
newexample <- example[type == 'q', .(
  quarterly_reports = quarterly_reports %m-% months(rep(0:2, .N)),
  type = "m",
  gains = gains/3) ]
setorder(newexample, quarterly_reports)
newexample
#     quarterly_reports   type gains
#                <Date> <char> <num>
#  1:        2020-01-31      m  6000
#  2:        2020-02-29      m  6000
#  3:        2020-03-31      m  6000
#  4:        2020-04-30      m 10000
#  5:        2020-05-30      m 10000
#  6:        2020-06-30      m 10000
#  7:        2020-07-30      m 15000
#  8:        2020-08-30      m 15000
#  9:        2020-09-30      m 15000
# 10:        2020-10-31      m 20000
# 11:        2020-11-30      m 20000
# 12:        2020-12-31      m 20000
```

---

(This is likely much slower, kept for posterity.)

I don't know that this saves you a lot of efficiency in terms of `data.table`'s normal referential semantics, since it has to create a lot of rows (which I think are not done in-place). Either way,

```r
library(zoo)
library(data.table)
setDT(example)

newexample <- example[type == "q",][,rn:=seq_len(nrow(.SD))][, .(
  quarterly_reports = as.Date(seq(as.yearmon(quarterly_reports), length.out = 3, by = -1/12), frac = 1),
  type = rep("m", 3),
  gains = rep(gains, 3) / 3
), by = rn ][,rn:=NULL]
newexample <- rbindlist(list(newexample, example[type != "q",]))
setorder(newexample, "quarterly_reports")
newexample[]
#     quarterly_reports   type gains
#                <Date> <char> <num>
#  1:        2020-01-31      m  6000
#  2:        2020-02-29      m  6000
#  3:        2020-03-31      m  6000
#  4:        2020-04-30      m 10000
#  5:        2020-05-31      m 10000
#  6:        2020-06-30      m 10000
#  7:        2020-07-31      m 15000
#  8:        2020-08-31      m 15000
#  9:        2020-09-30      m 15000
# 10:        2020-10-31      m 20000
# 11:        2020-11-30      m 20000
# 12:        2020-12-31      m 20000
# 13:        2021-01-31      m 10000
```

(The use of `zoo::as.yearmon` suggested by @G.Grothendieck previous answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/47634838/3358272, in order to keep the dates as the last day of each month.)

Comment: The `seq(as.yearmon` can be shortened with `lubridate::%m-%`: `as.Date(quarterly_reports) %m-% months(0:2)`. No idea about speed. 'type' and 'gain' will be recycled, so no need for (the more explicit) `rep`. Cheers

Comment: Good point about recycling, yes I was trying to be explicit (I often distrust recycling, and working with `data.table::fcase` has reinforced that), but you're right, no need for that here. Thanks. (I am not a `lubridate` pro, good to learn, thanks again.)

Comment: You could actually do `months(rep(0:2, .N))` to avoid the dreaded `by` row. Should make a difference with OP's 3 million rows.